# How to deselect an entry in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

A friend of mine was making a basic program using tkinter when he realized that even when you deselect an entry, the cursor still remains in that entry until you select another one. My question is, is this a technical issue? Also, is there any way for me to fix this?
[image: An example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `widget.focus_set()` to change focus when mouse button is pressed

```
from tkinter import *


def change_focus(event):
    event.widget.focus_set()
    

root = Tk()

Entry(root).pack()
Entry(root).pack()

root.bind_all('<Button>', change_focus)
root.mainloop()
```